# Intellij 12 Code Completion ShortCut

Tags: intellij-idea

I just started using Intellij 12, and I cannot get Code Completion to work.  According to the manual, I should be able to hit enter or tab to select the suggestion.  For example, if write the code below, a suggestion box shows up showing a couple of suggestions (put, putAll).  How do I actually select one of those?  Very frustrated.  Thanks.

```
map.put
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try up and down cursors to select one and then hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer @user1888440 provided, you may want to look at the "Preselect the first suggestion" option in *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Code Completion*. When on that settings page, click the Help button to see the an explanation of the different options for the "Preselect the first suggestion" option.